# Need help formatting a string into a table

Tags: python

I want the user to be able to enter multiple authors and output the information in a formatted table. Column 1 has a minimum field width value of 20 and is left justified. Column 2 has a minimum field width value of 23 and is right-justified.

Currently, my program will only print out one author and number of books at a time. It prints the table every time you enter the input, I am trying to get it to ask the user to keep entering the input until they stop, then print out all of the authors and number of books on one table.

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VXft.png)

```py
column1 = input("Enter the column 1 header : ")
print("You entered : {column1}")
column2 = input("Enter the column 2 header : ")
print(f"You entered: {column2}")
header = [column1,column2]

data = []
authors = []
books = []
while True:
    author = input("Enter an author (-1 to stop input): ")
    if author == "-1":
        break
    book = int(input("Enter the number of books written by this author: "))
    data.append([author,book])
    print(f"Author: {author} ")
    print(f"Number of Books: {book}")

    format_string = '{name:16}{books:8}'
    print(format_string.format(name = 'Author', books='Number of books'))
    print('-' * 36)
    print(format_string.format(name = author, books=book))
    print(format_string.format(name = author , books=book))

for author,name in data :
    histogram= author + " "+ "*" * name
    print(histogram)
```

Comment: Hi :) your program print 2 lines each time, you just want one line at each while iteration ?

Comment: I want the program to keep asking to "Enter Author name" and "Enter number of books" until they stop the input, then print the table

Comment: This is already the case, isn't it ?

Comment: It prints the table every time you enter the input, I am trying to get it to ask the user to keep entering the input until they stop, then print out all of the authors and number of books on one table

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

The display of the result is in the while loop.

Put it outside.

```py
data = []
while True:
    author = input("Enter an author (-1 to stop input): ")
    if author != "-1":
        break
    book = int(input("Enter the number of books written by this author: "))
    data.append([author, book])
    print(f"Author: {author} ")
    print(f"Number of Books: {book}")

print(f'{"Author":16}{"Number of books":8}')
print('-' * 36)
for author, number in data:
    print(f'{author:16}{number:8}')
```

```
Enter an author (-1 to stop input): A
Enter the number of books written by this author: 4
Author: A 
Number of Books: 4
Enter an author (-1 to stop input): B
Enter the number of books written by this author: 9
Author: B 
Number of Books: 9
Enter an author (-1 to stop input): C
Enter the number of books written by this author: 2
Author: C 
Number of Books: 2
Enter an author (-1 to stop input): -1
Author          Number of books
------------------------------------
A                      4
B                      9
C                      2
```

Comment: Why did you move `author = input()`? OP's way was perfectly fine

Comment: Oups, I send the wrong refactor, thanks for noticing it